# Function return type from a NextJS function?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm working w/NextJS 13, a layout.tsx file and I see this --

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I understand that { children } above is destructing from props, but what's the second part?

I don't understand what's after the ":" --

```
{ children: React.ReactNode }
```

Is this the return type?

I don't see this appended to functions often, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: That's the *argument* type, not the *return* type. It means an object with a `children` prop of type `ReactNode` should be passed to the function (a.k.a. props). The return type is `JSX.Element`, although it's not explicitly specified. That's a really weird component BTW, what is it supposed to hook in to? What component would you call `ReactDOM.render` on?

Comment: @JaredSmith this is the standard wrapper for all pages in Next.js v13, it basically replaces `_app` and `_document` on previous Next.js versions.

Comment: @ivanatias ahh ok, I've only used next 11 & 12.

Comment: Ah, I see. We're pulling children out from React.ReactNode and then destructing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the return type, but the *parameter* type of the function.
Consider a simplified example:

```
function add({num1, num2}: {num1: number, num2: number}) {
   return num1 + num2;
}
```

This function destructures the object parameter and extracts `num1` and `num2` into their own variables. In addition, it specifies that the argument provided to the function must be an object with keys `num1` and `num2`, both of type `number`.

```
add({num1: 5, num2: '7'}); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

```
add({num1: 5, num3: 4}); // Argument of type '{ num1: number; num3: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{num1: number; num2: number; }'
```

Comment: This is sort of an inline interface. I understand now, thank you.

Comment: This is an inline *type*, not an interface. This is the same idea as defining the type for parameters that aren't objects. i.e., `function add(num: number) {...}`.